# Can you mix omnidirectional lights with a shadowmap?

Tags: glsl, shader, shadow

I have implemented PSSM (Parallel-Split Shadow Map) for my RPG. It uses only the "sun" (one directional light high above.

So my question is, is there a special technique to add say max 4 omni-directional lights to the pixel shader?

It would work somewhat along these lines :

```
At the shadowmap application (or maybe at its creation):
if in light: do as usual

else: check if any light is close enough to light this pixel (and if, don't shadow it).
```

Maybe this can even be done in the shadowmap generation (so filtering will be applied to those omni lights too)

Any hints or tips warmly welcomed!

Comment: ps. I know that with this technique the omni lights won't cast shadows but that is a drawback that I can live with (ie. I will place only small lights and far away from shrubberies and walls, say a light over a 'fire' would be OK).

Comment: I don't get the question. Are you looking for a shadow map algorithm supporting omni lights? Or some specific chunk of shader code doing what exactly?

Comment: I'm looking for a 'hack' where shadowmapping supports one light (the "sun") but where you can use several other 'local' lights (close lights) which might influence the a)shadow map creation or b) the shadow map application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is so obvious that the question itself suggests that you've gone too far into the hacks of 3D graphics and need to remember what all of this is actually supposed to be doing.

A shadowmap is a way to tell whether a particular location on a surface is in shadow relative to a particular light in the scene. The shadowmap answers the question, "Is there something solid between the point on the surface and the light source?"

If the answer to this question is "yes", then that light source does not contribute to the lighting computations for that point. If the answer is "no", then it does.

The color of a point on a surface is based on the incoming light from all light sources and the surface characteristics of that point on the surface (diffuse color, specular shininess, normal, etc). All of the computations from each light add into one another to produce the final color value that the point represents.

You generally also have various hacks. The ambient term is often used to represent lots of indirect illumination. Light maps can take the place of light from other sources that you're not computing dynamically in the shader. And so on. But in the end, they are all just lights.

Your lighting equation takes the light parameters (color, direction/position, or just the ambient intensity for the ambient light) and the surface characteristics (as stated above), and produces the quantity of light reflected from the surface. Since the reflectance from one light is not affected by the reflectance from other lights, you can compute this independently for each light.

All of these values are added together to produce the final value.

The fact that you can short-circuit the computation of one of these via a shadowmap test is irrelevant to the overall scheme. Just add the various lighting terms to one another, and that's your answer. There is no "special technique" to doing this; you just do it.

Comment: You might actually be right here but let me think it over as one part of the idea was to be able to use the fast percentage closer filtering PSSM:s use, and use it for the 'other lights'. Nice clean-up of my question though, impressive! I have actually done quite a lot of hacky things (have tied most together though), normalmaps, cube-reflections, specular, animation etc. I definitely got lost somewhere deep down there but as I said, I have to think it over, I'll be back in a day or so.